# Is there a way to reprint the screen in gdb gef?

Tags: gdb

I am using `gdb-gef` and I've searched the manual several times for the answer to this question. Sometimes I run a lot of commands and I would like to re-draw the current program state the way gef displays it when I step through the program (registers + stack + list view, etc...). Yes, I am able to get much of the same info with the `info registers`, `info frame`, etc... But I have not found a way to do this and it would be helpful.

Comment: This command is called `context`. See [context](https://hugsy.github.io/gef/commands/context/).

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot... I searched for "state", "redraw", "refresh, "reprint", "display", "show", gosh I had no clue it would be called "the context menu" but now it makes sense...